# How to match a string from an array at the beginning of another string

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

I want to case-insensitively match a string from my array, `TOKENS`, at the beginning of another string followed by a space or the end of the line.

My tokens array looks like:

```
2.4.0 :013 > TOKENS = ["m", "o"]
 => ["m", "o"]
```

When I try to match each element from my array, it is picking out the wrong results:

```
2.4.0 :009 > data_col = ["M", "b", "Mabc", "abc m b"]
 => ["M", "b", "Mabc", "abc m b"]
...
2.4.0 :015 > data_col.select{|string| string =~ /^[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]([[:space:]]|$)/i }
 => ["M", "b"]
```

This is matching both the "M" and the "b" entries even though "b" does not appear in my list of TOKENS.  How do I modify my regular expression so that only the proper value, "M" will be matched?

I'm using Ruby 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use:

```
TOKENS = ["m", "o"]
DATA_COL = ["M", "b", "Mabc", "abc m b"]
RE = /^(?:#{Regexp.union(TOKENS).source})(?: |$)/i

DATA_COL.select{ |string| string[RE] }
# => ["M"]
```

Breaking it down a bit:

```
Regexp.union(TOKENS).source # => "m|o"
/^(?:#{Regexp.union(TOKENS).source})(?: |$)/i # => /^(?:m|o)(?: |$)/i
```

---

`/^[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]([[:space:]]|$)/i` isn't a good idea inside a loop. Each time through you force Ruby to create the pattern; Efficiency is important inside loops, especially big ones, so create the pattern outside the loop then refer to the pattern inside.

The next problem is that `Regexp.union` has a concept of the correct case it should match:

```
Regexp.union(TOKENS).to_s        # => "(?-mix:m|o)"
```

The `(?-mix:` part is how the Regular Expression engine remembers the flags for the pattern. When the pattern is embedded inside another pattern they continue to know what they should look for, causing us to gnash our teeth and weep:

```
/#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/i # => /(?-mix:m|o)/i
```

The trailing `i` is telling the pattern it should ignore case, but the embedded `i` is not set so it's honoring case. And that's what is breaking your pattern.

The fix is to use `source` when embedding like I did above.

See the Regex "[options](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Options)" section for more information.

Comment: One more issue is that the original regex had alternation (created by `Regexp.union`) inside of a character class (the square brackets).

Comment: Although this only seems to cause the `b` to falsely return true when you have the `(?-mix:)` structure.

Comment: Ah yes, it's interpreting `?-m` as a character range inside the character class, which includes `b`.

Comment: Alternation can't occur inside a character set, all characters inside the set are equally important and all are honored, so `|` has no special meaning. `?-m` isn't interpreted as a range, because `(?-` is a token. See the documentation for "options" mentioned at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Right, I meant that the output of `Regexp.union` is supposed to be alternation, but putting it inside of the square brackets makes it so it doesn't work. I do think it's being interpreted as a range, at least in the version of Ruby I've got open at the moment (2.0). Running `"b" =~ /^[(?-mix:m|o)]$/` returns 0, while changing the range to exclude `b` (that is, `"b" =~ /^[(?-aix:m|o)]$/`) makes it return nil. If that isn't going on, how do you explain that `'b'` gets matched by the OP's original regex? I don't see anything in the "options" documentation addressing that.

Comment: To be clear, I don't mean that `?-m` is interpreted as a range in your regex, just that it seems to work that way inside the character class in OP's original regex.